# jQuery validate different field depending on a checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate a form I have on one of my applications.

The form (simplified) is as follow :

```
<form id="my_form" action="#" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input id="my_hidden_input" type="text" style="display:none;">
    <input id="my_select_checkbox" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <select id="my_select_1" class="select valid" type="select">
    <select id="my_select_2" class="select valid" type="select">
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is to validate the following : if the checkbox is checked, I check that a value is selected in my first select, and if the checkbox isn't checked, I check the selected value of my second list.

I tried something like :

```
$('#my_form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        my_hidden_input:{
            "checkboxSelect": true,
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        console.log($("#monitors_start").value);
        return false;
    }
});


jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "checkboxSelect",
    function() {
        if ($("#my_select_checkbox").attr('checked'))
            return $("#my_select_1").val();
        else
        return $("#my_select_2").val();
    }, "test addMethod"
);
```

But it seems i'm not getting it properly... If anybody could help it'd be greatly appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: Is your function being called?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Kscj/8/

Comment: @CSL well, i'm trying to `console.log` something before the return but nothing prints out

Comment: @BritneySpearsFan I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the depends option like

```
var validator = $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        my_select_1: {
            required: {
                depends: function () {
                    return $('#my_select_checkbox').is(':checked')
                }
            }
        },
        my_select_2: {
            required: {
                depends: function () {
                    return !$('#my_select_checkbox').is(':checked')
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {}
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u92rM/)